Uncaught TypeError: sys is undefined when using Chakra UI with Vite
I'm getting these errors when trying to integrate Chakra UI into my React application using Vite.
Uncaught TypeError: sys is undefined
    ChakraProvider provider.js:15

The above error occurred in the <ChakraProvider> component:

ChakraProvider@https://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@chakra-ui_react.js?v=b3e29175:2973:36

This is my App.jsx, error only occurs once I add the ChakraProvider
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
      <ChakraProvider>
          <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);

The rest of my application is just from the Visual Studio React and ASP.NET Core template and behaves without any issues.

This syntax won't work in Chakra UI v3.0.0. Not sure why. Change the version used in package.json to version 2.10.3
"@chakra-ui/react": "^2.10.3",

and reinstall with
npm i


Sweet thanks, this was the solution I'd ended up finding works best

I was just facing this issue as well, According to https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui following is the syntax that is working
import { ChakraProvider, defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"

// Do this at the root of your application
function App({ children }) {
  return <ChakraProvider value={defaultSystem}>{children}</ChakraProvider>
}

apparently we have to import defaultSystem from chakra-ui & pass it to ChakraProvider
https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui?tab=readme-ov-file#usage

import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { ChakraProvider, defaultSystem } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
      <ChakraProvider value={defaultSystem}>
          <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);

// Add the value={defaultSystem} inside the ChakraProvider
Your below problem is solved that way.
hook.js:608 The above error occurred in the  component:
at ChakraProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@chakra-ui_react.js?v=aa2353d4:2694:18)

